# How to mock nested properties and objects and their functions?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the code below which I would like to test, but I'm not sure whether it is possible or not.

I have EF repositories and they are put together to a class as public properties. I don't know exactly whether it is bad solution or not, but it is easier to manage the code and its dependencies. Only the testability is still a question.

Purpose of my test is injecting data via

> administrationRepository.ModuleScreen.GetAll()

method and catch the result. I know that it can be tested once it is deployed, but I want the tests in build time in order to have as fast feedback as possible.

I went through questions and answers here, but I cannot find answers. In my code I got to the point where the property is set up, but when I call the administrationRepoMock.Object.ModuleScreen.GetAll() ReSharper offers only the methods coming from Entitiy Framework and not the Moq related functions.

It is possible what I want? If so, how? Is my design suitable for this? If not can you give me articles, urls where I can see examples?

Repository:

```cs
public interface IModuleScreen
{
    IEnumerable<DomainModel.Administration.ModuleScreen> GetAll();
}

public interface IAdministrationRepository
{
    IModuleScreen ModuleScreen { get; }
}

public partial class AdministrationRepository : IAdministrationRepository
{
    public virtual IModuleScreen ModuleScreen { get; private set; }

    public AdministrationRepository( IModuleScreen moduleScreen )
    {
        this.ModuleScreen = moduleScreen;
    }
}
```

Application:

```cs
public partial class DigitalLibraryApplication : IDigitalLibraryApplication
{
    private IAdministrationRepository _administrationRepository;
    private IMapper.IMapper.IMapper _mapper;
    private IDiLibApplicationHelper _dilibApplicationHelper;

    #region Ctor
    public DigitalLibraryApplication( IAdministrationRepository administrationRepository, IMapper.IMapper.IMapper mapper, IDiLibApplicationHelper diLibApplicationHelper)
    {
        _administrationRepository = administrationRepository;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _dilibApplicationHelper = diLibApplicationHelper;
    }
    #endregion

    public IEnumerable<ModuleScreenContract> GetModuleScreens()
    {
        //inject data here
        IEnumerable<ModuleScreen> result = _administrationRepository.ModuleScreen.GetAll();

        List<ModuleScreenContract> mappedResult = _mapper.MapModuleScreenToModuleScreenContracts(result);

        return mappedResult;
    }

}
```

Test code:

```cs
[Test]
public void ItCalls_ModuleRepository_Get_Method()
{
    List<SayusiAndo.DiLib.DomainModel.Administration.ModuleScreen> queryResult = new List<SayusiAndo.DiLib.DomainModel.Administration.ModuleScreen>()
    {
        new DomainModel.Administration.ModuleScreen()
        {
            Id = 100,
        },
    };

    var moduleScreenMock = new Mock<IModuleScreen>();
    moduleScreenMock.Setup(c => c.GetAll()).Returns(queryResult);

    administrationRepoMock.SetupProperty(c => c.ModuleScreen, moduleScreenMock.Object);


    var mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper.IMapper.IMapper>();
    var dilibApplicationHerlperMock = new Mock<IDiLibApplicationHelper>();


    IDigitalLibraryApplication app = new DigitalLibraryApplication( administrationRepoMock.Object, mapperMock.Object, dilibApplicationHerlperMock.Object );

    app.GetModules();
    //issue is here
    administrationRepoMock.Object.ModuleScreen.GetAll() //???
}
```

Comment: By testing, I want to know that my business logic returns with the correct data. That is why I want to mock the repository and controlling its return value and see how other parts of the code works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a refactoring of your test that passes when run. You can update the pass criteria to suit you definition of a successful test.

```
[Test]
public void ItCalls_ModuleRepository_Get_Method() {
    // Arrange
    List<ModuleScreen> queryResult = new List<ModuleScreen>()
    {
        new ModuleScreen()
        {
            Id = 100,
        },
    };
    //Building mapped result from query to compare results later
    List<ModuleScreenContract> expectedMappedResult = queryResult
        .Select(m => new ModuleScreenContract { Id = m.Id })
        .ToList();

    var moduleScreenMock = new Mock<IModuleScreen>();
    moduleScreenMock
        .Setup(c => c.GetAll())
        .Returns(queryResult)
        .Verifiable();

    var administrationRepoMock = new Mock<IAdministrationRepository>();
    administrationRepoMock
        .Setup(c => c.ModuleScreen)
        .Returns(moduleScreenMock.Object)
        .Verifiable();

    var mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper>();
    mapperMock.Setup(c => c.MapModuleScreenToModuleScreenContracts(queryResult))
        .Returns(expectedMappedResult)
        .Verifiable();

    //NOTE: Not seeing this guy doing anything. What's its purpose
    var dilibApplicationHerlperMock = new Mock<IDiLibApplicationHelper>();

    IDigitalLibraryApplication app = new DigitalLibraryApplication(administrationRepoMock.Object, mapperMock.Object, dilibApplicationHerlperMock.Object);

    //Act (Call the method under test)
    var actualMappedResult = app.GetModuleScreens();

    //Assert
    //Verify that configured methods were actually called. If not, test will fail.
    moduleScreenMock.Verify();
    mapperMock.Verify();
    administrationRepoMock.Verify();

    //there should actually be a result.
    Assert.IsNotNull(actualMappedResult);
    //with items
    CollectionAssert.AllItemsAreNotNull(actualMappedResult.ToList());
    //There lengths should be equal
    Assert.AreEqual(queryResult.Count, actualMappedResult.Count());
    //And there should be a mapped object with the same id (Assumption)
    var expected = queryResult.First().Id;
    var actual = actualMappedResult.First().Id;
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```